# Publish WPF Application with localdb without click-once

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first, localdb

i am a absolute beginner... and it is my first database based application.

i would like to drop a c# wpf application with database (2 tables) on an offline single-user-client.
its a wpf c# ef6 code first app. on my machine with vs2019 it runs as intended.
now trying to run it on a new set up win10 machine it doesnt even start.

- net 4.7.2 is installed
- sql server 2016 localdb is installed manually (.msi)

Here is the connectionString for my db:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="ZuschnittverwaltungDB" connectionString="data source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|Datadirectory|\ZuschnittverwaltungDB.mdf;initial catalog=Zuschnittverwaltung.ZuschnittverwaltungDB;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

i assume that i am missing a big point but i cant find any solution after searching several days...

Edit1:

AttachDbFilename=|Datadirectory|\ZuschnittverwaltungDB.mdf ->

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location));
```

i am thankfully for every approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LocalDB is required to be installed separately on the client machine.

If you want to "drop" deploy your database along with the application itself you should use a self-contained database like [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/index.html).

If you choose to stick with using LocalDB, you need to ensure that your database file is deployed to `|Datadirectory|\ZuschnittverwaltungDB.mdf` (or whatever path you have specified in the configuration file) on the target machine.

Comment: as i mentioned above sql server 2016 localdb is installed ->https://download.microsoft.com/download/4/1/A/41AD6EDE-9794-44E3-B3D5-A1AF62CD7A6F/sql16_sp2_dlc/en-us/SqlLocalDB.msi

Comment: Did you deploy the database to `|Datadirectory|\ZuschnittverwaltungDB.mdf` on the client machine then?

Comment: thats the bind   ---         AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location));

Comment: What error message are you getting when you run the app?

Comment: well. here i struggle. it doesnt even start. i am not that familiar with exceptions when it doesnt even start... its located in the taskmanager for several seconds and then disappears... maybe i should go more in depth for debugging to find out whats wrong...

Comment: Yes, you need to implement some kind of logging to be able to determine what actually happens when it fails.

Comment: oh and i missread your first answer... shame on me... i tried to let the app create the database as it does when i start debugging it. and i copy/paste the database from my pc

Comment: This is dangerous as the user may not have the appropriate permissions. I would recommend to you use a self-contained database if you intend to deploy the DB along with your app.

Comment: thanks for your suggestions. i read a lot about that it is "ok" to use localdb if its a small single-user-app and i wonder how they could get it work...

Comment: Make sure that the database can be accessed in the specified location. That's how to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that everything i did first was right. Didnt changed the code or installed anything new.

just ran
cmd-> sqllocaldb delete mssqllocaldb

copied the databasefiles from my pc to the specified folder and it worked...

Thanks @mm8. I could find more ErrorInformations in the windows event manager

cheers